Which is this movie about childhood friends who move apart, the girl becoming an actress?

Live action, English movie (probably Hollywood)
Watched around 2000, give or take (mostly give) a few years in India. So, given that it's English, it's likely that it was a 90s movie, or very late 80s.
The guy gets work in a movie in which the girl is to star
One planned scene in the movie involved the girl's clothes getting torn off. The guy suggests a workaround with a crate or something falling from above just as the clothes get torn off, hiding her behind it.
There were Hindi and Malayalam movies with similar storylines, so I'm afraid I might be conflating details: I think there was a necklace given to the guy by the girl as a keepsake.
I haven't seen the ending, but I presume the girl sees the necklace and realizes who the guy is.


Found it!!!!!
It's a TV movie.  Hallmark Channel Star Struck, 1994
Director: Jim Drake
Cast:
Kirk Cameron, Chelsea Noble, J.T. Walsh, Ned Eisenberg, Desiree Marie, Anne Haney, D.W. Moffett, Hadley Eure, Keith Flippen, Marion Guyot

Runner and Robyn were summer camp sweethearts. She became a Hollywood
  star and Runner stayed at the farm. Finally Runner takes grandma's
  advice and goes LA to win his lost love back. He gets a job as her
  gofer but she doesn't recognize him. Everyone thinks his down-to-earth
  'nice' is an act, while he keeps hoping Robyn will remember...

Here is the movie in Youtube.




Welcome to Movies&TV. Can you please add plot of the movie in your own words or from IMDB or wikipedia? It helps the users to decide whether it is the same movie without going through the youtube video. Explain how it is the same movie the OP is describing. .Keep visiting the site. You will like it!
